# Android View : Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap

I've got a problem when my app start on the AndroidVirtualDevice 
The user

package com.test.imageviewproject;

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE;

    Bitmap monBitmapAMoi;
    String imagePath;

     // assignation des ids du menu
    private static final int GALERIE_MENU_ID    = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int LARGEUR_MENU_ID    = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int HAUTEUR_MENU_ID    = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int COULEURPXL_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
   // private static final int BOUTONRETOUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    // assignation des éléments du menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu parambmp) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(parambmp);

        parambmp.add(0, GALERIE_MENU_ID,    0, "Galerie").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        parambmp.add(0, LARGEUR_MENU_ID,    0, "Largeur").setShortcut('4', 's');
        parambmp.add(0, HAUTEUR_MENU_ID,    0, "Hauteur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        parambmp.add(0, COULEURPXL_MENU_ID, 0, "Couleur pxL").setShortcut('5', 'z');
      //  parambmp.add(0, BOUTONRETOUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Couleur pxL").setShortcut('6','z');
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

 // événements lancés selon les éléments du menu appelés
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case GALERIE_MENU_ID:
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                return true;

            case LARGEUR_MENU_ID:
                int  w = monBitmapAMoi.getWidth();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Largeur bmp : " +w,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case HAUTEUR_MENU_ID:
                int  h = monBitmapAMoi.getHeight();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hauteur bmp : "+h,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case COULEURPXL_MENU_ID:
                int c = monBitmapAMoi.getPixel(10, 10);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Couleur du pixel en 10x10 : "+c,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

           /* case BOUTONRETOUR_MENU_ID:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Seicom",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;*/
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public static class MyView extends View {

        /*private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;*/

        /*
         * les 4 éléments de bases pour permettre le dessin
         */
        private static Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private static Path mPath;
        private static Paint mBitmapPaint;
        private static Paint mPaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            // instanciation du path
            mPath = new Path();
            // instanciation du paint avec tramage à on.
           // mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }


        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            // creation du bitmap ou objet du trait
           // mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            // instanciation du canvas
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        /*
         * methode appelée dynamiquement quand on dessine
         */
       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // assignation de la couleur au canvas
            //canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);
            // assignation du bitmap au canvas
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            // assignation du chemin au canvas
            //canvas.drawPath(imagePath, mPaint);
        }

        public static void setBitmap (Bitmap bitmap){
            mBitmap = bitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //ImageView monBitmapAMoi = new ImageView(this);
        //monBitmapAMoi.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();//recupère l'URI de l'image sélectionnée dans le onCreate(bundle)
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            /*
             * Gestion du path de l'image
             */
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap test = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));

            MyView.setBitmap(test);
            View img = new MyView (this);
            setContentView(img);


           // ImageView monBitmapAMoi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
          // monBitmapAMoi.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath)); //conversion de l'image affichée en bitmap

        }
    }
}
```

But when the application starts it crashes every time, i don't find the my mistake on the code. Ecplise can't find the mistake too :-/
This is my logcat :

```
11-28 14:29:09.416: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:82)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at com.test.imageviewproject.MainActivity$MyView.onSizeChanged(MainActivity.java:122)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:6897)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6824)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Even in watchong the logcat i don't understand my mistake

I can't find my error could you help me please ?

Comment: Please post the logcat error and relevant code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your logcat indicates, you got null pointer exception caused by code in line 122 MainActivity.java

```
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 14:29:09.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1011): at
     com.test.imageviewproject.MainActivity$MyView.onSizeChanged(MainActivity.java:122)
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. But how fix my mistake ? Please